# Logical grouping in HTML for results pulled from object

Tags: javascript, html

I am successfully iterating through an object/array from an API and am able to take three parameters, Author/Title/Description, and place results from each parameter into their own lists. In other words, all Authors from the array are being placed in html into one list, all Titles are placed into one list, all descriptions are placed into one list.

How can I group the results logically, as in, for each book have the results Author/Title/Desc placed into one area on the page ...(div?)?

```
const searchButton = document.getElementById('searchbtn')
const form = document.getElementById('myform')
const author = document.querySelector('.author')
const title = document.querySelector('.title')
const description = document.querySelector('.description')

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    searchButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const inputSearch = document.getElementById('books').value
        const bookUrl = ('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + inputSearch)
        fetch(bookUrl)
        .then (res => res.json())
        .then (obj => {
            obj.items.forEach((book, index) => {
                const listAuthor = document.createElement('li')
                const listTitle = document.createElement('li')
                const listDescription = document.createElement('li')
                listAuthor.innerText = book.volumeInfo.authors
                listTitle.innerText = book.volumeInfo.title
                listDescription.innerText = book.volumeInfo.description

                author.appendChild(listAuthor)
                title.appendChild(listTitle)
                description.appendChild(listDescription)
            })
            form.reset()
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: We can’t possibly help you without seeing your current code as a [mre], along with a succinct explanation on where you’re getting stuck performing this grouping, as well as some sample data. Please see [ask]

Comment: I added my code as you were posting this comment. How could I possibly explain my goal any clearer?

Comment: 'for each book have the results Author/Title/Desc placed into one area ', so you want a div (book-container) and list books one by one within that div ? what kinda grouping do you need to achieve ? <div> <p>{Author}, {Title}, {Desc} <p> </div> ? just a big list of books with corresponding properties within a single div ?

Comment: I am doing a very simple student project. I only need the results to display on one page. My current code takes the info from the API and populates it into three seperate lists for each category. I instead need "book 1, Author/Title/desc" then "book 2, author/title/desc." I am a beginner student and do not really know what the grouping you presented means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if I misinterpreted your issue.

```
const booksArray = [
  {author: 'Eric Hoffer', title:'The Ordeal Of Change', desc: 'In times of change...' },
  {author: 'Eric Hoffer', title:'The True Believer', desc: 'Learners inherit the earth' },
  {author: 'Eric Hoffer', title:'The Passionate State Of Mind', desc: 'while the learned...' },
]


const groupBooks = (books) => {
  const bookContainer = document.createElement('section');

  books.forEach((book, index) => {
    // extract values
    const {author, title, desc} = book;

    // construct composite book article
    const bookDescription = `
          <article>
            <small>book ${index + 1} </small>
            <h2>Title: ${title}</div> 
            <h3>Author: ${author}</h3> 
            <p>Desc: ${desc}</p> 
          </article>
          `;

    // append it to the main container above
    bookContainer.append(bookDescription);
  })

  console.log(bookContainer);
  //to see the results...
  document.body.prepend(bookContainer);

}

groupBooks(booksArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to apply what you've typed here, although I am not sure of how to do so, I am a student and do not have the hang of this yet.

Comment: make sure you feed the 'appropriate' data into the function. You may have to tweak the parameters on your own... this is just for your reference. this is based on the sample array I've created above.